# SQL query to get all posts with their revision data

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I am trying to export all posts with their revision. So that i can see what has been changed at what time and who changed it.

I am not getting any idea how to do this. My query so far:-

```
select p.id, p.post_parent, p.post_title
from wp_posts p
join wp_posts p1 on p.id=p1.post_parent
where post_type in ('hg-scratch-card','revision') and
post_status='publish';
```

but it does not seem to work.

Any help regarding this will be really appreciated.

**Edit:-**

```
select * from wp_posts where post_type in('hg-scratch-card','revision') and post_parent in
(
    select id from wp_posts where post_type='hg-scratch-card'
)
order by post_modified DESC
```

It returns all post revision of a specific post type:- "hg-scratch-card" but the parent post is missing in the rows.

Comment: post_type is ambiguous, as is post_status - the error message would have told you that.

Comment: update your question add  a proper data sample and the expected  result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select p.id, p.post_author, p.post_date, p.post_title, p.post_content, p.post_status, p.post_modified, p.post_parent, p.post_type,
pm.meta_key, pm.meta_value,
u.display_name
from wp_posts p
inner join wp_postmeta pm on pm.post_id=p.id
inner join wp_users u on u.id=p.post_author
where p.post_type in('hg-scratch-card','revision') and
p.post_parent in(select id from wp_posts where post_type='hg-scratch-card') and
LEFT(pm.meta_key, 1)!='_'
order by post_modified DESC
```